# Plotting function with matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

please how can i plot the Rosenbrock function to get the image above :[here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosenbrock_function)

Comment: have you tried anything or are you hoping to find some good soul to code it for you? If it's the first case: post more details, what have you tried (actual code) and where you're stuck. BTW: the title is not descriptive

Answer (score 3):

To get the 3d plot at the top, click on the image in the WP article to get the image page. Check the bottom, the person who created the image was good enough to include the python script that created it in the comment section. It requires matplotlib (of course). As for the other images, it's hard to tell what's going on mathematically and there's no source given so I doubt anyone but the people who created them could reproduce them accurately.